# Fail to send email from my server

Tags: php, server

I`m getting following error email when i trying to send emails from my web site.

This error coming when i trying to send sctivition email through my web site. But when i trying to send recover password mail it is sending successfully. There can`t be error in my code. So could any one help me out.

```
 This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

    lmbkarunanayake93@gmail.com
    host spam1.thewebhostserver.com [IP Address]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    550 High probability of spam
```

Comment: Quote 'There can`t be error in my code. So could any one help me out.'.? We really would like to see your code.

Comment: "high probability of spam" says it all...

Comment: @Marc B yes.but i`m trying to reset password with same email address. its working fine.Why it says "high probability of spam" only when i`m trying to activate account?

Comment: because spam detection isn't JUST checking the From: line. email content is analyzed as well, and whatever you're sending to trigger that message obviously pushed the spam score over the threshold

Comment: [link]http://koko.lk/activate.php?&uname=$uname&random=$ran[link]  This is the code i use for send email. But when i try with com instead of lk domain it`s working fine. for a example [link]http://koko.com/activate.php?&uname=$uname&random=$ran[link]. What should i do to get rid of this?